# How can I use count with INNER JOIN and date,where together on one SQL sentence

Tags: sql, join, count, inner-join, where-clause

I have two sql tables below, I want to join two tables with inner join. And then I want to count alert number for device like Result table below. But I want to do this for some date range(for examle between date2- date6).

I try to write a sql sentence but it did not work. How can I do this?

First Table:

```
Message  Date   ID
```

```
Alert   date1   1
Alert   date2   2
Alert   date3   3
Alert   date4   1
Alert   date5   1
Alert   date6   2
Alert   date7   3
```

Second Table:

```
Device   ID
```

```
PC1   1
PC2   2
PC3   3
PC1   1
PC1   1
PC2   2
PC3   3
```

My Final Table:

```
     Message  Device   Count
```

```
    Alert   PC1   2
    Alert   PC2   2
    Alert   PC3   1
```

My SQL Sentence:

```
select table1.message,table1.date, table2.device
       Count (table2.device)
From table1 INNER JOIN table1 
      ON table1.id =  table2.id
Where DATEDIFF(DAY,TimeStamp,GETDATE()) between date2 and date6 
Group By table2.device
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: "it did not work" is not a problem description, why didn't it work?

Comment: I am using mssql. and I have an error like that : 'Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'table1' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.'

Comment: There is a problem with your expected output.  _Which_ message do you want to display for each device summary?  There are many message corresponding to each row in your expected output.

Comment: yeap I think it was about date. But I want to know  how many alarms do I have  between date2 and date6 for all PC.I want to actually count this result.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question...what output do you want?

Comment: @desscartes,Check below query it's give your expected result

Comment: sorry I could not understand..I expected  to count alert for device. For example for PC1 could have alert messages different  date. I want to count thıs between date2 and date 6. @Mansoor I will check  query thankss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TABLE #Table(_Message VARCHAR(100), _Date VARCHAR(100),ID INT)
CREATE TABLE #Table1(_Device VARCHAR(100),ID INT)

INSERT INTO #Table(_Message , _Date ,ID )
SELECT 'Alert','date1',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alert','date2',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alert','date3',3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alert','date4',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alert','date5',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alert','date6',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alert','date7',3

INSERT INTO #Table1(_Device ,ID )
SELECT 'PC1',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PC2',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PC3',3 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PC1',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PC1',1 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PC2',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 'PC3',3

SELECT _Message , _Device,COUNT(*) [COUNT]
FROM #Table
JOIN
(
SELECT ID,_Device
FROM #Table1
GROUP BY ID,_Device
)A ON A.ID = #Table.ID 
WHERE _Date BETWEEN 'date2' AND 'date6'
GROUP BY _Message , _Device

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: This will return every record in the first table, which doesn't appear to be what the expected output wants.

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen,Thanks for suggesstion.Now check I Updated above query

Comment: @ Mansoor I try but I have an error like that :   "The multi-part identifier "#Table2" could not be bound."

Comment: @desscartes,It works fine.Did you execute my posted query..? I didn't use #Table2 in anywhere

Comment: sorry  it is my mistake, I correct query like that but stiil have same error  "The multi-part identifier "#Table1" could not be bound." Thanks

Comment: @desscartes Can you post your query

Comment: Of course;    select  #Table.Message,  #Table1.Device COUNT(*) [COUNT]
  from #Table
  JOIN 
  ( 
  SELECT #Table1.ID,#Table1.Device
  FROM #Table1
  group by #Table1.ID,#Table1.Device
   )A ON A.ID=#Table.ID
  WHERE #Table.Date BETWEEN 'date2' AND 'date6'
  GROUP BY #Table.Message,#Table1.Device

Comment: select Message,Device,COUNT(*) [COUNT] from #Table JOIN ( 
 SELECT #Table1.ID,#Table1.Device FROM #Table1 group by ID,Device ) A ON A.ID = #Table.ID WHERE Date BETWEEN 'date2' AND 'date6' GROUP BY Message,Device

Comment: I changed your query little bit use this and check